# How to get the ID of the newly created record

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object

How to get the `ID` that was created in a custom object

Below is my scenario, I'm creating a new record in the `Work_Order__c` object using the APEX class:

```
// object instance with memory allocation.
    Work_Order__c wo = new Work_Order__c();
    wo.Est_Hours__c = 89;
    wo.Instructions__c = 'this is a test';
    insert wo;
```

and it successfully created and I have looked at the system.debug log and this is what I'm getting in the log:

> USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|Work_Order__c:{Instructions__c=this is a test,
>   Est_Hours__c=89, `Id=a0j1a000000cbuFAAQ`}

My question is there a way I can hold that newly created ID and update to a different object ?

Comment: Immediately after the insert, `wo.Id` will be set to the ID of the object so you can use that value in code that follows. See e.g. [Id assignment when creating sObjects in code](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4528/id-assignment-when-creating-sobjects-in-code).

Comment: duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57234/how-to-get-id-of-inserted-record-via-apex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get that.

One as mentioned by Keith, the ID field of the variable wo will be assigned the value.

Other than that you can get the value in After Trigger as well.

```
for(Your_Object__c  i:trigger.new) {
     ID id = i.Id;
}
```